# Showing a syntax error eventhough it works when use the query in sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM book1 WHERE";
foreach ($terms as $each) {
$i++;
if($i == 1){
    $query.="keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
}
else{
    $query.="OR keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
}
}
$hello=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($hello)>=1)
{
while($i= mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{   
    echo '  ';
    echo '<h2><a href="'.$i['link'].'">'.$i['bname'].'</a></h2>';

}       
}
```

The following error shows up when i run the code

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '%paul%'' at line 1

but the same query gave results when i ran it on mysql 
Can someone help me find the problem with my code ?

Comment: Have you ever tried to replace "keywords LIKE '%$each%'" to ' keywords LIKE "%$each%" ' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need space at

```
if($i == 1){
    $query.=" keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
            ^^^
}
else{
    $query.=" OR keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
            ^^^
}
```

Otherwise query become

```
SELECT * FROM book1 WHEREkeywords...
```

Missing `;` at `$hello=mysql_query($query);`

> Note mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.Can't believe that i didn't think of that.Thanks a lot